# With Redux-Form, how to dispatch from a ReduxFormField onChange event?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, recompose

I'm getting the following error:

**'dispatch' is not defined  no-undef**

What I'm trying to do is make it so whenever the user selects one of the ReduxFormField radio buttons, the form auto submits.

What is the right way to be able to do this..dispatch from onReduxFormFieldChange?

```
...
import {
  Field as ReduxFormField,
  reduxForm,
} from 'redux-form';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
...

class MyFormRadioInputs extends React.Component {
  onReduxFormFieldChange = (e, newValue, previousValue) => {
  if (newValue) {
    dispatch(submit(MYFORM));
  }

  render() {
    const { MyItems } = this.props;
    return MyItems.map((item) => (
        <ReduxFormField
          key={item.id}
          name="MyItemId"
          type="radio"
          value={item.id}
          label={item.title}
          onChange={this.onReduxFormFieldChange}
        />
    ));
  }

}

const withForm = compose(
  reduxForm({
    form: MYFORM,
    ...
  })
);

const MyForm = (props) => (
    <Form>
        <MyFormRadioInputs
          myItems={props.myItems}
        />
    </Form>
);

MyForm.propTypes = {
  myItems: PropTypes.shape....    
};

export default withForm(MyForm);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are connecting your component to redux-form, but you are not ever connecting your component to the redux store, which means you don't have the ability to dispatch actions (including redux-form actions such as `submit`).

I haven't used `recompose` before, so I'm not sure if/how you get dispatch through it, but with standard react-redux you would need to add something like the following at the bottom of your file:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ submit: (formName) => dispatch(submit(formName))});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(withForm(MyForm));
```

and then your component's `onReduxFormFieldChange` implementation becomes:

```
onReduxFormFieldChange  = (e, newValue, previousValue) => {
    if (newValue) {
        this.props.submit(MYFORM);
    }
}
```